# Javascript push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create an object like this:

```
"store1":
{
  "isbn":"3129321903",
  "title":"here comes the title",
  "author":"author of the book"
},
{
 "isbn":"3333333333",
 "title":"title of second book",
 "author":"author of second book"
}
"store2":
{
  "isbn":"3333311111",
  "title":"title of book from store2",
  "author":"author of book from store2"
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
var storeArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < response.data.bookInfo.length; i++){
  var keys = Object.keys(response.data.bookInfo[i]);
  var storename = keys.filter(key => key != 'isbn' && key != 'metadata'); // get storename

  if(storeArray[storename] == undefined){
    storeArray[storename] = response.data.bookInfo[i];
  }
  else{
    storeArray[storename].push(response.data.bookInfo[i]);
  }
}
```

But this just gets me the following error:

> TypeError: storeArray["amazon"].push is not a function

When I use `storeArray[storename] = response.data.bookInfo[i]`, it only shows me one row in console, I would like to add the response data to storeArray[storename] to get a list of books by store.

Comment: Post sample `response.data`

Comment: You need `storeArray[storename] = [ response.data.bookInfo[i] ];` so you get an array

Comment: The structure you defined in your question is not valid.  If you meant for each store to contain an array of books, then you need to use array brackets, `[]`.  You can't just stick commas in between normal objects.

Comment: And you cant use `push` to an object. Your desired output is an object and not an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that your `storeArray[storename]` is not an array. 
At

```
storeArray[storename] = response.data.bookInfo[i];
```

you just assign a value to the `storeArray[storename]` which is not an array. You need first to create an array and then put that element into it.

```
storeArray[storename] = [ response.data.bookInfo[i] ];
```

and at the next iterations you will have an array with one element and can use `push` on it.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

`push` is a function of `Array` itself. So: `storeArray.push(...)`

Comment: I know how to push to storeArray itself, but I wanted to push to the key ["dynamic storename"]. But thanks for your quick reply.